# AAPT: error: attribute buttonColor (aka com.example.*appName*) not found

Tags: java, android

I have searched far and high for a solution and tried to also understand this error but there seems not to be much info about this particular error.

Here is the activity.xml line where is saying the error is residing (I have two of these as I have two buttons)

```
<info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnMakeAnAccount"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:text="Make An Account"
            android:textColor="@color/pink"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/black"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="4dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
            />
```

at first I was using this library --> implementation 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'

however due to my emulator not working I came to learn to use this library instead --> implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1' the library details of use is found here https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button I thought in my code I have adapted it so it could work but obviously not lol

this is the code of me casting the button and its methods in my main btnLogin = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
btnMakeAnAccount = (FButton)findViewById(R.id.btnMakeAnAccount);

```
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });

    btnMakeAnAccount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you share the coolers.xml file here. I think "black" color not available in it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove button colour and use some another attribute like background color or something else.

Answer (score 0):

In xml, instead of `fbutton:buttonColor` use `fbutton:fButtonColor`

```
fbutton:fButtonColor="@color/black"
```